# Promises as way of controlling state

Tags: design-patterns, typescript, promise

I would like your comments on the use of promises in a part of my code.

I have a View, lets call it `Foo`. `Foo` implements Interface `EmbeddableView`.
I have Foo embedded in view `Bar`. `Foo` is unaware that it is embedded anywhere and  `Bar` does not care about the content of `Foo`, only if it's valid or not.  The way this happends is the interface `EmbeddableView` has a `function` like `getValidationPromise` returning a promise.

When view `Foo` resolves the promise, `bar` is notified that its content either rendered invalid or valid.

However, that validation state change is not a one time thing. It will jump back and forth. It is no longer a promise on the completion of an operation. It can fail, re-fail, success and maybe fail again. Would you say promises is still a meaningful way of implementing this?

Any comments about how this could be implemented in typescript/javascript in a meaningful way is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any (MV*) framework for this?

Comment: No, a single promise is not able to represent state that changes back and forth. You can use multiple promises (each representing the validity at the time of calling `getValidationPromise`), or something else.

Comment: `getValidationPromise` would only (in this case) be called once when `Foo` is embedded in `Bar`.  Do you know of any libraries providing what now looks more like a signal object?

Comment: Yes, if you're looking for a `Signal`-like object you should definitely have a look into FRP. Or just use a event emitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look into Observables, for example in [RX.js](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS).

From your question:

> validation state change is not a one time thing. It will jump back and forth. It is no longer a promise on the completion of an operation. It can fail, re-fail, success and maybe fail again. Would you say promises is still a meaningful way of implementing this?

From this (very good) [Introduction to Reactive Programming](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754):

> A Promise is simply an Observable with **one single emitted value**. Rx streams go beyond promises by allowing **many returned values**.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

> However, that validation state change is not a one time thing. It will jump back and forth. It is no longer a promise on the completion of an operation. It can fail, re-fail, success and maybe fail again. Would you say promises is still a meaningful way of implementing this?

No.

You could use a mechanism with events:

```
interface EmbeddableView {
    addValidationListener(listener: (valid: boolean) => void): void;
}
```

In the implementation, store the listeners in an array, then call all the listeners each time the status changes:

```
class Foo implements EmbeddableView {
    private listeners = [];

    public addValidationListener(listener: (valid: boolean) => void) {
        this.listeners.push(listener);
    }

    private fireValidationListeners(valid: boolean) {
        for (let cb of this.listeners)
            cb(valid);
    }
}
```

Beware of memory leaks if the part of code that creates the listeners (Bar) is deleted / regenerated. In this case, you need to add something to remove the listener (for example, a method `removeValidationListener` called with a handler returned by `addValidationListener`).